# Kusto (KQL): Count of all columns where value < 0

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Objective: Count all columns where values < 0.  Columns could be either positive or negative

[Example as shown:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5HxL.png)

```
Table
| summarize count() by Field
| where (Col1 <0 or Col2 <0 or Col3 <0 or Col4 <0)
```

The result I get back is:

```
A | 1
B | 1
C | 0
```

New to Kusto - what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try reversing the order of the filter and the aggregation, i.e.:

```
Table
| where (Col1 <0 or Col2 <0 or Col3 <0 or Col4 <0)
| summarize count() by Field
```

or use the `countif()` aggregation function:

```
Table
| summarize countif(Col1 <0 or Col2 <0 or Col3 <0 or Col4 <0) by Field
```